# Send JSON Payload in RequestContent of HttpSend with POST in SharePoint 2013 Workflow in Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, web-services, json

I have a SharePoint 2013 Workflow in Visual Studio. I need to call an external Web API using POST and send some JSON payload. I couldn't find any proper documentation to achieve it. Can anyone please guide me, with some code samples?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this article will guide you through.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: I am trying to achieve this in SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio Workflow, which doesn't let you write code.

Comment: Then use a custom code activity: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/08/28/how-to-develop-a-workflow-code-activity-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx